# how to use the .Write function for wav module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, wav

It's probably something simple and stupid, but the module doesn't have enough documentation in neither the github page or the npm page.

Can someone write a code example of using the .Write function for writing a wav file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a very simple example using [`tonegenerator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tonegenerator) to generate raw PCM data:

```
var tone   = require('tonegenerator');
var wav    = require('wav');
var writer = new wav.FileWriter('output.wav');

writer.write(new Buffer(tone(220, 5))); // 220Hz for 5 seconds
writer.end();
```

`wav.FileWriter()` is a simple wrapper around `wav.Writer()` to write to a file directly, similar to this:

```
var writer = new wav.Writer();

writer.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('output.wav'));

writer.write(new Buffer(tone(220, 5)));
writer.end();
```

Long story short: `wav.Writer()` creates a [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) that you can `.write()` raw PCM data to. Most WAVE properties are [hardcoded](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-wav/blob/9da7eba47c9b0416f2ba1cd80a89c131036d2c9f/lib/writer.js#L65-L71).

Comment: I feel so stupid right now.
but seriously, how did you know that? I tried reading through the code and I still didn't get it.

Comment: @bubakazouba I inferred it from the source :) (and I have to agree: the documentation of the module is pretty lacking...)